# Form rebuild without using buttons

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I'm trying to figure out how to rebuild a form without using a button click trigger. Instead, I'm looking to rebuild whenever a blur event occurs on a textfield. All non-button form types lack the #submit value. It doesn't seem possible to trigger a form rebuild with `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` unless the submit callback is triggered. Demo code below.

```
function test_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['form_wrapper'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="form_wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  if (isset($form_state['textfield_vale'])) {
    $textfield_vale = $form_state['textfield_vale'];
  }
  else {
    $textfield_vale = 'not set';
  }

  //will not trigger page rebuild
  $form['form_wrapper']['test_textfield'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#value' => 'Value = '.$textfield_vale,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'test_result',
      'wrapper' => 'form_wrapper',
      'event' => 'blur',
     ),
  );

  //will trigger page rebuild, changing the textfield value
  $form['form_wrapper']['trigger_rebuild'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'I don\'t want to press it',
    '#submit' => array('submit_rebuild'), //has #submit value unique to buttons
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'test_result_with_button',
      'wrapper' => 'form_wrapper',
    ),
  );

  return $form;
}

function test_result($form, &$form_state) { //unable to set $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE
  $form_state['textfield_vale'] = 'textfield trigger'; //TRUE;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  return $form['form_wrapper'];
}

function submit_rebuild($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['textfield_vale'] = 'button trigger'; //TRUE;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function test_result_with_button($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['form_wrapper'];
}
```

Is there a way to trigger a form rebuild without clicking a button (perhaps with an ajax command)? Alternatively, how can I change my code to allow an ajax callback to change $form_state values?

Comment: If not a button what else should trigger the rebuild? Onchange?

Comment: Preferably a blur event, but onchange would work as well.

Comment: How is that blur being triggered?

Comment: Have you tried https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/126952/15055?

Comment: The blur event would trigger whenever I deselect the textfield. The solution you linked might work but would probably require a lot of rebuilding due to avoiding drupal's default submit and validation functions.

Comment: Then you could try the other solution and blur and submit at once? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/127158/15055

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear. I'm trying to rebuild the form using a process that usually requires a submit button. Both proposed solutions assume $form['#method'] = 'get'; is used for the module. I'd like to avoid using a GET method, since it removes drupal form validation and would require a significant code rebuild.

Comment: I think this GET thing only comes from the question's code and isn't actually necessary for the autosubmit to work. But I'm unsure about that.

Comment: Returning to this problem. AJAX is causing me some significant trouble. I might be able to leverage the following behavior: pressing the ENTER key within a textfield triggers the 'click' event of the form's first submit button. I'd still need to figure out how to initiate the same behavior using a blur event. Will revisit prior suggestions and see if I can adapt them to my current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that jQuery can be used to click a Drupal submit button ([source](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11638/how-to-programmatically-trigger-a-click-on-an-ajax-enabled-form-submit-button)). I can use an event listener to trigger a submit event by interacting with a specific button that can be hidden anywhere on the form. Below is my solution based off of my original demo code.

```
<?php

function test_form($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_add_js('
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.test_form = {
    attach: function() {
      $("#test_textfield").blur(function() {
        $("#trigger_rebuild").mousedown();
      });
    }
  }
}(jQuery))', 'inline');

  $form['form_wrapper'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="form_wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  if (isset($form_state['textfield_vale'])) {
    $textfield_vale = $form_state['textfield_vale'];
  }
  else {
    $textfield_vale = 'not set';
  }

  //will not trigger page rebuild
  $form['form_wrapper']['test_textfield'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#value' => 'Value = '.$textfield_vale,
    '#id' => 'test_textfield',
  );

  //will trigger page rebuild, changing the textfield value
  $form['form_wrapper']['trigger_rebuild'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'I don\'t want to press it',
    '#id' => 'trigger_rebuild',
    '#submit' => array('submit_rebuild'), //has #submit value unique to buttons
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'test_result_with_button',
      'wrapper' => 'form_wrapper',
    ),
  );

  return $form;
}

function submit_rebuild($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['textfield_vale'] = 'button trigger'; //TRUE;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function test_result_with_button($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['form_wrapper'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always handled changing form values in the form build or form_alter function itself. I can't remember where I saw to do this, but I've never been able to alter the form in the ajax callback itself.

Have your form trigger an ajax callback. This should return the form or piece of the form in question, like your `test_result_with_button()` function.

When an ajax callback is triggered, the build method and alters are run again. Add logic in your build / form_alter to make updates to the form or form_state based on whichever action was triggered. Information about how the rebuild was triggered will be available in $form_state['triggering_element'].

Comment: I haven't been able to update the form after AJAX callback. I can change variable values but the form elements will not change unless $form_state['rebuild'] is called. I think I might be able to get what I want with careful javascript. And to clarify, I'm trying to change the attributes of elements (disable some buttons, change the text of a textfield). Replacing them with AJAX will cause problems.